# How to change color of checkbox values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to change color of checkbox values like if it's checked it shows text in green if its unchecked it shows color in red here is simple input type

but I am not sure how I color these true-value and false-value if someone knows please help, Thanks! P.S I have put the whole code now if that be helpful for people to understand my problem.

```
            <label>Other Information:</label>
            <textarea v-model="student.otherInformation"></textarea> <br /><br />

            <input type="checkbox" v-model="student.agree" true-value="I want to receive promotions"
            false-value="I Don't want to receive promotions">

            <span>Agree receive our promotions.</span><br><br>
            <button type="submit" class="button" >Add a new student</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: how or where you are showing the checkbox value?

Comment: You can add a class to the checkbox depending on `student.agree` and use that to change the color.

Comment: I am showing that inside an array @Usama

Comment: can you please give an example as I am so new to web development @ChrisG

Comment: If you are this new, why post here instead of browsing the docs? https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes

Comment: as I am not good at reading docs and understanding it :) @ChrisG

Comment: That only means you need to become good at understanding it. Practice, in other words. Stackoverflow is not a free tutorial service for newbies I'm afraid.

Comment: @ChrisG I can understand that but I am trying to achieve this task from last hour couldn't achieve it that's why posted here :)

Comment: In that case put your attempt in the question as [mre] so we can take a look.

Comment: Ok, i have edited a code a lil so you can understand what I am trying to do :) @ChrisG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind style:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      student: {name: "", gender: "male", age: 0, country: "", hobby: [], otherInformation: "", agree: ""},
      students: [{name: "Mike", gender: "male", age: 23,country: "ZM", hobby: ["Studying"], otherInformation: "I want say nothing but try your best.", agree: "I Don't want to receive promotions"}, {name: "Emma", gender: "famale", age: 18, country: "PK", hobby: ["Playing Game",
 "Travelling"], otherInformation: "Please contact me anytime.", agree: "I want to receive promotions"}, {name: "Emily", gender: "famale", age: 20, country: "BD", hobby: ["Studying", "Eating", "Travelling"], otherInformation: "Tell me your problem.", agree: "I Don't want to receive promotions"}],
      countries: [{name: "China", abr: "CN"}, {name: "Zambia", abr: "ZM"}, {name: "Bangladesh", abr: "BD"}, {name: "India", abr: "IN"}, {name: "Pakistan", abr: "PK"}],
      hobbies: ["Studying", "Playing Game", "Eating", "Travelling"]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addStudent() {
      this.students.push(this.student)
    },
    removeTask: function(index) {
      this.students.splice(index, 1);
    },
    handleHobbies(hobby) {
      this.student.hobby.includes(hobby) ? this.student.hobby =  this.student.hobby.filter(h => h !== hobby) : this.student.hobby.push(hobby)
    },
    //  method for selecting style
    colorIt(i) {
      return this.students[i].agree === 'I want to receive promotions' ?  'color: green' : 'color: red'
    },
  },
})
```

```css
.true-value {
  color: Green;
}
.false-value {
  color: Red;
}
.btn-danger {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <h3>Student Information Collection</h3><hr>
  <form class="basic-grey"  @submit.prevent="addStudent">
    <div class=" form-group">
      <label for="name">Student Name:</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" required v-model="student.name">
    </div>
    <label>Gender:</label >
      Male<input type="radio" v-model="student.gender" value="male" >
      Female<input type="radio"  v-model="student.gender" value="female"><br />
    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input id="age"  type="number" v-model="student.age"> <br />
    <label>Country:</label>
    <select v-model="student.country">
      <option disabled selected value="">Please select your country</option>
      <option v-for="(country, i) in countries" :key="i" :value="country.abr">
        {{country.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
    <label>Hobby:</label>
    <span v-for="(hobby, idx) in hobbies" :key="idx">
      <input type="checkbox" @change="handleHobbies(hobby)" value="Studying">{{ hobby }}
    </span><br />
    <label>Other Information:</label>
    <textarea v-model="student.otherInformation"></textarea> <br />
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="student.agree" true-value="I want to receive promotions"
    false-value="I Don't want to receive promotions">
    <span>Agree receive our promotions.</span><br>
    <button type="submit" class="button" >Add a new student</button>
  </form>
  {{student}}
  <h3>Students list</h3><hr>
  <table id="rounded-corner">
    <thead>
      <th class="rounded-company">Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Hobby</th>
      <th>Receive Promotions</th>
      <th class="rounded-q4">Operation</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(student, index) in students" :key="index">
        <td>{{student.name}}</td>
        <td>{{student.gender}}</td>
        <td>{{student.age}}</td>
        <td>{{student.country}}</td>
        <td>{{student.hobby}}</td>
        <!--  bind style and call method -->
        <td :style="colorIt(index)">{{student.agree}}</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn-danger" @click="removeTask(index)">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know vue, but you can do it in plain html and css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
/* The container */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #F00;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Custom Checkboxes</h1>
<label class="container">One
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Please do not use, recommend or link to w3schools.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) (also note that OP is using Vue)

Answer (score 0):

First of all put text in semantic HTML like the label
and then put the below code to target the input on the check and uncheck

> ```
> input[type="checkbox"]+* {
>         color: red !important;
>     }
>
>     input[type="checkbox"]:checked+* {
>         color: green !important;
>     }
> ```